# ERROR : ACTION 4.0.5.0 UPGRADE SPCONTENTDATABASE FAILED TO ROLLBACK

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-server, upgrade

I encountered the error

> ERROR : ACTION 4.0.5.0 UPGRADE SPCONTENTDATABASE FAILED TO ROLLBACK

while upgrading from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and I have about 300 gig free space on my server I had already searched the web but I did not find any usable solutions.I have enough free space

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: did you used SQL Express version?

Comment: no I used sql server 2012

Comment: How large is the content database that you are trying to attach to the web application? When you say that you have about 300Gb free space on your server, you are talking about the SQL server? I've seen reports that the upgrade of this type can require three times the original database size as free storage on the SQL server, so if the database you're trying to attach is > 100Gb, free up some disk space on the SQL server and try again. Also ensure that the auto-growth settings for the database are set to a reasonably large size.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check all your Mount Points at **Administrative Tools** >> **Computer Management** >> **Disk Management**. In some circumstances, the volumes where the LDF and MDF files are stored, may be significantly less than expected. Therefore, the solution will be the increase the storage for the particular drives, at least during the attach and detach process.

The issue specifically relates to when the space on the SQL drive where the MDF and LDF are located have run out of space. You will want to ensure it has at least double the space requirement to satisfy the MDF file alone, the LOG file is going to be approximately a third of that file during the upgrade.

The event log should mention this, as per the below:

> “Examine the drives containing the specified databases’ log and data
>   files.  Free space on these drives or move the database files to
>   another drive.  A drive should have enough free space for the largest
>   database file on it to autogrow twice. For more information about this
>   rule, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=163560.”

Comment: Did this help you?